# Pointer Invalidation with std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I'm writing toy C++ code to learn it and game dev, wrapping SDL along the way; all it does right now is load a BMP image and display it on the screen in a loop. Posting only relevant code.

**EDIT:** I'm revising this post down to the MVCE. The problem can be found much more directly.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>

class Surface {
public:
    Surface(SDL_Surface*);
    ~Surface();
    SDL_Surface* mSurface;
}

Surface::Surface(SDL_Surface* surface) {
    mSurface = surface;
}

Surface::~Surface() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(mSurface);
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        throw("Failed to SDL_Init: " + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL TEST", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 960, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    const char * imgPath = "test.bmp";
    std::vector<Surface> surfaces;
    surfaces.push_back(Surface(SDL_LoadBMP(imgPath)));
    SDL_BlitSurface(surfaces.begin()->mSurface, // memory access violation here
                            NULL, screenSurface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

What it comes down to is that the pointer inside the `Surface` object loaded into a `vector` becomes invalidated. I read around and thought that maybe it had to do with needing a custom copy constructor, but making one like this didn't solve it:

```
Surface::Surface(const Surface& other) {
    mSurface = other.mSurface;
    mIsWindowSurface = other.mIsWindowSurface;
}
```

Comment: If `SDL_BlitSurface`  works fine with hard coded path, then you should probably trouble shoot in your `loadMedia`. Maybe check the return value of `SDL_LoadBmp` before `Surface` constructor? Is there any SDL API to get last error? I never worked with SDL to suggest such error look up API.

Comment: @elimad, The pointers all look okay at the point that `SDL_BlitSurface` gets called. I also used `SDL_GetError` to see if anything is set before blitting, but nothing comes out. There's some kind of invalidation happening between when the `Surface` gets created in `loadMedia` and when the pointer from it gets used in `update`; but it gets "fixed" if those two lines are uncommented (not even used).

Comment: How are you initializing the `mWindowSurface.pointer()` rather, `mWindowSurface` ?

Comment: That happens in a `Window` class. It holds an `SDL_Window*` member and the constructor calls `SDL_CreateWindow`. I can't imagine that's the problem though; everything points to the `Surface`.

Comment: I've tested SDL 2.0 just now, seems to work fine. But your code is not compilable (`SDL_Pointer`). Can you please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Done. I think the problem is much more straightforward than I made it out to be. It has something to do with pointers inside of objects stored in STL containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define a copy-constructor, so the default copy constructor is used and this doesn't do what you want.

In the line

```
 surfaces.push_back(Surface(SDL_LoadBMP(imgPath)));
```

here is what happens:

1. Create a temporary `Surface` whose `mSurface` pointers to the newly allocated surface
2. Copy this `Surface` into the vector using the copy-constructor (or copy-assignment operator)
3. Destruct the temporary `Surface`, which calls `SDL_FreeSurface`.

Then when you go onto do `surfaces.begin()->mSurface,`, you are trying to work with a surface that has already been freed.

To fix this prior to C++11 you will need to make your copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator semantically make a copy, or use a reference-count mechanism to ensure that `SDL_FreeSurface` is only called once there are no more active pointers to the surface.

In C++11 there are a lot more out-of-the-box fixes; one of them is to disable copying for your class, and implement a move-constructor and move-assignment operator, and/or use `emplace_back( SDL_LoadBMP`... instead of `push_back`.

Comment: That makes sense! I hadn't thought about the destructor being called. I first tried just swapping out for `emplace_back` but the problem still exists; any ideas? I'm attempting the move constructor/operator right now.

Comment: make sure you're doing `emplace_back(SDL_LoadBmp`..., not `emplace_back(Surface`. Disable copying for your class so that you get a compiler error instead of an accidental copy if something tries to copy it.

Comment: That was it. Two questions. 1) In my case, I cannot use a move or copy constructor, because the old object will always have its dtor called, correct? 2) Is there a argument to be made for or against doing emplace vs move, besides "depends on the application's need"? i.e. in my case, if I could use either, would one be better than the other?

Comment: Make it so that the move-constructor and move-assignment operator set the old object's pointer to null, and make the destructor not try to free the surface it if was null.

Comment: Emplace seems a bit simpler to me, but if you also support moves then you can do things like grow your vector. (If you can neither copy nor move then you can't add items beyond the vector's `capacity()`)